# FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists! / Java

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to get rid of the the error "FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already". I use my server app for the cloud messaging. Every hour I have to create new google credentials because of the expiration and I thought that I do also have to initialize the App again with the new credentials, is this correct?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:512)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:222)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:215)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:202)
    at cnotifier.access.FCM.initializeFirebaseApp(FCM.java:70)
```

My Method to create Credentials

```
private final static String MESSAGING_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
private final static String[] SCOPES = { MESSAGING_SCOPE };
private static GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = null;
[...]

public static void createCredentials() throws IOException  {
  FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("/etc/cnotifier/service-account.json");
  googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount).createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
        googleCredentials.refresh();
    }
```

My Method to initialize the app

```
/**
 * Initializes Firebase SDK
 */
public static void initializeFirebaseApp() throws IOException {
  FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder().setCredentials(googleCredentials).build();
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
}
```

Sending the message

```
public static String sendMessage(Message message) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
  String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
        
  return response;
}
```

Sending notifications to users works so far, but I dont know how to reinit the FirebaseApp when the Google credentials are invalid. I tried to reinit the FirebaseApp when credentials expired and called initializeFirebaseApp() again with new credentials.

Any help for better understanding?